# Determine if image is already compressed/optimized?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, optimization, compression

Is there a Node.js library that can be used to determine if an image is already compressed/optimized?

One solution I thought of is that I could compress an image and then compare the before/after file size to make the determination. But I'm wondering if there is another, less intensive way to determine accomplish this.

Comment: You can try to check a [`lighthouse`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse), they have a good audit for the images, like a part of websites. But I'm not sure if you can just run it for the images.

Comment: That is a good idea but I'm specifically referring to local images on the file-system. Not images on a website necessarily.

Comment: I see, maybe it can be also useful: [tinify-nodejs](https://github.com/tinify/tinify-nodejs), [google article about image optimization](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization).

Comment: Not sure about node module, though you can use `ImageMagick` to determine it via `identify -verbose yourimage.jpg`. Output will be something like `Compression: JPEG Quality: 80`. You can run it in node using `child_process`.

Comment: Infact there is a node module for `ImageMagick` too. [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagickal)

Comment: Hi @Jake, what solution did you find?

Answer (score 0):

I use [gulp-imagemin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-imagemin) to optimize the images (if they are already optimized it leaves them unchanged, otherwise it optimizes them) with a task in [gulpfile.js](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp#sample-gulpfilejs) like this:

```
gulp.task( 'images', function() {
    return gulp.src( 'path_img_folder/**/*' )
        .pipe( plugin.imagemin( {
            optimizationLevel: 7,
            progressive:       true,
            interlaced:        true,
            verbose:           true
        } ) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'path_img_folder/' ) );
});
```

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation for imagemin that shows that it won't compress an image if it's already compressed?

Comment: Look at this link: https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-imagemin/blob/e1e3cf2a35ef1ff1f200aa5432d1167a8f347039/index.js#L80